# Possibilities of removing echo of any sound

Tags: science-based, planets

Assume, you wake up in a room on a strange alien planet.
You tried to shout but could not hear any echo back of your sound.

Is there any technology/concept or possibility to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called an [anechoic chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anechoic_chamber), and it does exactly what it says in the name, it's a chamber with no echo.

> An anechoic chamber (an-echoic meaning "non-reflective, non-echoing, echo-free") is a room designed to completely absorb reflections of either sound or electromagnetic waves. They are also often isolated from waves entering from their surroundings. This combination means that a person or detector exclusively hears direct sounds (no reverberant sounds), in effect simulating being inside an infinitely large room.

Apparently spending long periods of time in one is quite disconcerting, as by design they're heavily sound insulated from the outside world. Eventually all you hear is your own breathing and heartbeat.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, yes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anechoic_chamber
The walls in such a room are of a special shape to break the soundwaves und reflect them between the other wall parts to break them again and again.